# Remove closed and migrated questions from Review tabs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, closed-questions, migrated-questions

I think the closed and migrated questions should be removed from the Review tabs. Whatever the problem was with these questions has been solved so there's no need to have them in these lists.

**Edit:** To reply to the comments below, I think there should be a threshold (a quality score that would factor votes, close votes and flags), below which a question disappears from the Review tab. For example, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976697/path-how-to-become-a-ceo): it has five close votes, a -5 score and probably a number of flags too (which we cannot see). What is the likelihood that a question that poorly rated could ever be reopened?

Now if the poster indeed makes significant changes to his question, it's a different issue. In that case, maybe the question could be given a second chance and reappear in the Review tab. But if no changes have been made, and the question is *really* poorly rated, chances are it can be removed from the Review tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed and locked posts are now ignored in the Low Quality and First Posts queues.

To allow for review of closed questions ([Brad Mace's concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101281/remove-closed-and-migrated-questions-from-review-tabs/101282#101282)), there's a Reopen queue where eligible posts can be found.

Answer (score 5):

What if they were closed or migrated incorrectly? Those decisions can also be reviewed and undone if necessary. Showing them in the review allows double-checking the way things were handled.

Comment: But sometime I see questions that have been closed by 5 users. By then, shouldn't we assume that the question has been reviewed properly?

Comment: Not necessarily; if all closings were proper there would be no need to allow reopening. Sometimes people see one close vote and pile on without considering it very carefully. Even if the closing was proper, the question may have been edited and improved and now be ready to be reopened.

Comment: But then *all* closed questions should be added to the review?

Comment: If a user edits a question, it can be re-opened.  Without highlighting this possibility (removing these questions from that and/or similar views), these *edited* closed questions would become quickly buried.  If you feel that a question no longer adds value to the site then vote to delete it *and it will disappear from the review tab*.  That said, I think it would be reasonable to hide 'closed as duplicate' from the review tab as these are much less likely to be re-opened -- and if the user really wants to make a case, they can always raise the issue here, on Meta.