# Mark and/or filter closed questions as such in the review tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

On [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) (and other sites, too!), we get a lot of honeypot questions that attract low-quality answers and are eventually closed. These answers then show up under the review tools.

While the review page is right to show these answers because they are indeed low quality, they aren't very actionable in their own right:

- Many (most?) of the questions have little chance to be reopened, so a reviewer editing, flagging, prompting a user to revise their answer is pointless at best and borderline sadistic at worst.
- In the cases where the closed question is savable, the community would want to revise the question before any of the answers anyway.

There was a previous suggestion to just [avoid showing posts attached to closures or migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101281/remove-closed-and-migrated-questions-from-review-tabs), but I don't think it needs to be that drastic: a simple `[closed]` attached to the end of the question title would suffice. [random's suggestion in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112809/mark-closed-questions-as-such-in-the-review-tools/#comment-292893) to provide a *closed question* filter would be also welcome.

This way, reviewers can look to deal with the questions to which these low quality answers are attached without having to waste a lot of time improving answers when the core problem hasn't been fixed yet.

How about it?

Comment: What are you not doing to these answers that you would be doing if their parent questions were still open?

Comment: @PopularDemand Generally commenting to tell them that we expect more from answers than a single line, or in rare cases, improving the answer myself. Prompting people to expand an answer to a question that's just on its way to eventual deletion is a bit sadistic.

Comment: @MarkTrapp What about questions that are closed but aren't earmarked for deletion? As the theory goes, reopening closed questions is not out of the ..uh.. question.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's a good point, although I think that's an even stronger motivator for a `[closed]` designation in question titles: we want to revise the question that the low quality answer was posted to moreso than just revise the answer.

Comment: Would like a filter for posts on closed questions, so those under 3k can focus first on those still open

Comment: @MarkTrapp True. I agree that having [closed] in the title would be handy, but I also think we should avoid using that as an automatic "you can ignore this answer" pass.

Comment: same for answers as well?

Comment: @waffles yeah, that'd be the primary use-case, actually. When reviewing, I want to know when an answer is attached to a closed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a simple [closed] attached to the end of the question title would suffice.

True, this got me a few time, added to both the expanded and non expanded views for **answers**.

Comment: to be deployed today